# How can I view my total reputation across all sites?

Tags: support, reputation, stack-exchange, network-profile

Is there a way to view my total reputation across all sites on the Stack Exchange network in a single place? Or can I only view it site-by-site?

Comment: why this limit of 200+ reputation? So nice to new one here to see reputation growing... =/ I can't understand. =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the flair tab on your profile. Underneath the flairs for the site is a flair for your combined profiles, including (roughly), your combined reputation.

This only includes sites on which you have 200+ reputation.

It might be possible to write a tool to better calculate total reputation with [the API](https://stackapps.com/).

Comment: Thanks. The big reputation I already have is 68. =( Time will change this. =)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ interesting that you can go to the flair tab of another person's account from a link, but you can't navigate there normally (no flair tab is shown)

Answer (score 2):

With [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), it's possible to view the exact total (as of last Sunday morning every week, when it updates) with [this cross-site query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882182/total-reputation-networkwide-for-a-single-user). At the time of writing, [mine](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882182/total-reputation-networkwide-for-a-single-user?AccountId=6085540) is 117110 while my flair says only 101k:

[image]

Your total is [6979](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882182/total-reputation-networkwide-for-a-single-user?AccountId=458850); you'll need your network account ID which you can find in the URL of your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current):

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results (site nvarchar(250)
                       , reputation int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union all'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + ''', reputation
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users
where accountid = ' + CAST(##AccountId:int## AS nvarchar) + ''
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
  and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
-- AccountId: The global account ID of the user, which you can find in the URL of their network profile. Visit this link: http://stackexchange.com/users/current to see your own ID.

--print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select sum(reputation) as 'Total reputation'
from #results

drop table #results
```